# What's wrong with custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-view

I have this error in logcat when start my app:

> Process: pc.dd.fragment_animation, PID: 25093
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pc.dd.fragment_animation/pc.dd.fragment_animation.MainClass}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

This in my xml in main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="pc.dd.fragment_animation.newFragment"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my child in custom Adapter:

```
public class myListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {


public myListAdapter(Context context, int resource, Integer[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, null);
        }

        Integer objects = getItem(position);

        if (objects != null) {
            ImageView tt1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id._fragmentImage);
            TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id._fragmentNickanme);
            TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id._fragmentDescription);

            if (tt1 != null) {
                tt1.setImageResource(objects);
            }

        }

        return v;
    }}
```

And final, this is my Fragment where i'am try to do my custom ListView:

```
public class newFragment extends Fragment {
Integer[] items = new Integer[]{R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.picture};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);
    ListView myListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listFragment);
    myListAdapter adapter =
            new myListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    myListView.setAdapter( adapter);
    return view;
}}
```

*Note:  R.id.listFragment is in main_activity.xml.* 
And below code fragment_listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/_fragmentImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/picture"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#efefef"
        android:layout_margin="6dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/nickname"
            android:id="@+id/_fragmentNickanme"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#282828" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/string_small_text"
            android:id="@+id/_fragmentDescription"
            android:textSize="6pt"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to load Fragments into a ListView?

Comment: Look at your Fragment class... `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview` doesn't seem to be the correct layout that you want to use

Comment: @cricket_007, why?

Comment: 1) `R.id.listFragment` is not an id in that file. 2) `R.layout.fragment_listview` is also used by the Adapter class to load a row of the ListView.

Comment: @cricket_007, I do not know how to fix it? The best thing would probably be in the main class, simply connect the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i'am just do it's in my main class:

```
 ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listMainAct);
    myListAdapter adapter =
            new myListAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    myListView.setAdapter( adapter);
```

And delete `newFragment` class, thx **cricket_007** for hint :)

Comment: You are welcome to have a Fragment class with a ListView, you just needed to use the correct XML references in the Java code.